# This code creates a browse button to select a file. How do I change it to allow me to select a folder instead of a file inside a folder

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, swt

```
browseButton = new Button(controlGroupForSingleRun, SWT.PUSH);
    browseButton.setText("Browse ...");
    data = new GridData();
    data.widthHint = 80;
    browseButton.setLayoutData(data);
    browseButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event){
            lookForExeClick();
        }
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event){
            widgetSelected(event);
        }
    });
```

This code generates a browse button on an Eclipse plugin GUI, how can I make this button just select a directory and not a specific file.  Right now it is selecting a file.  Can someone maybe provide me with the odified code to allow this to happen.  Thank you.

As requested here is the lookforExClick() method.

```
So I changed the filedialog to directorydialog as the answer below mentioned.  But here is my method you asked for: 

    private void lookForExeClick (){
    boolean notLegal = false;
    while(!notLegal){
        exeChooser.setText("Choose an executable file");

        singleExeFilePath = exeChooser.open();

        String tmp = exeChooser.getFileName();

        if(tmp.equals("")){
            notLegal = true;
            return;
        }
        else if(tmp == null){
            notLegal = true;
            return;
        }
        if(!tmp.equals("") && !tmp.endsWith(".exe") && !tmp.endsWith(".bat") && !tmp.endsWith(".jar")){
            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "Vulnerabilities Viewer",
                "Please input a legal executable name!"
                );
        }
        else {
            notLegal = true;
        }
    }

    exeLocationText.setText(singleExeFilePath);
    pureExeFileName = exeChooser.getFileName();

    // Set selection to newLocation.
    last.setSelection(false);
    for(int i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
        radios[i].setSelection(false);
    }
    newLocation.setSelection(true);
}
```

What do I take out or comment to get the browse button to work for a directory selection.  Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: The code you show doesn't select anything, show us the `lookForExeClick` method which I assume actually does the selection.

Comment: as requested I added the method for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with a DirectoryDialog, use it instead of the FileDialog.

```
    DirectoryDialog dlg = new DirectoryDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    String directoryPath = dlg.open();
    System.out.println(directoryPath);
```

Edit: Now that you added the lookForExeClick() here is what I would do, if I understood your code right:

```
private void lookForExeClick() {
    DirectoryDialog exeChooser = new DirectoryDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell());

    String pureExeFileName = null;

    String directoryPath = exeChooser.open();
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if (fileName.endsWith(".exe") || fileName.endsWith(".bat") || fileName.endsWith(".jar")) {
            pureExeFileName = fileName;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pureExeFileName == null) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(), "Vulnerabilities Viewer", "NO exe file found in directory");
        return;
    }

    exeLocationText.setText(pureExeFileName);

    // Set selection to newLocation.
    last.setSelection(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        radios[i].setSelection(false);
    }
    newLocation.setSelection(true);
}
```

Edit: Based on your comment I would do something like this:

```
    DirectoryDialog dlg = new DirectoryDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    String directoryPath = dlg.open();
    File file = new File(directoryPath, "MyFileName.exe");

    // if you already have the generated file on the file system
    Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    // if you will generate the straight to a stream
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: sure then what would I change this line too     String tmp = exeChooser.getFileName();    Is there a getdirectory or something for it?  Thanks.

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you.  However, it still looks for an exe file to be in the folder. The idea that I want is the brose button will allow me to select a directory and save the file that I generate in that directory.  Not select an .exe file.  

Based on your code that you provided I can select a directory but it looks for an .exe file in the folder.  How do I fix that?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Where would you ad this code?  In the lookForExeClick() method?  I will be generating a file not inputting a file.  Please advise.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post the complete code, or at least the part with FileDialog/DirectoryDialog since it is not in the lookForExeClick(). The problem is that your code is quite confusing. I don't see the reason for the while loop if you only want to write one file into a directory...

Comment: yea I understand the confusion.  It is because I am refactoring code that has already been established. It will only be outputting one file into the destination location that I choose in the dialog box that pops open when I click on browse.  Does that make sense?  Doe that help?  Let me know.  I can provide the code if you'd like.

Comment: ignore my previous comment......yea I understand the confusion.  It is because I am refactoring code that has already been established for another project.  To make things simpler to understand. in the gui I have a text box where the user enters the name of the file he wants to generate/output.  And the browse button is to make it so that the user can select the directory/folder to save the output file in.  Does that clear up the confusion?  What modifications would you make to the lookForExeClick() method.  How would the new method look?  Please advise.  Thank you.